# Rails: How to filter and sort products?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

`Product` has the following attributes:

- shop
- model
- price

`Model` belongs to:

- brand

Given `@products`, like:

```
Shop    Brand    Model    Price
----    -----    -----    -----
Ebay    Sony     S-100    500
Ebay    Sony     S-200    1000        (in Target it's cheaper)
Ebay    Dell     D-55     300
Target  Sony     S-100    600         (in Ebay it's cheaper)
Target  Sony     S-200    900
Amazon  Dell     D-33     100
```

I would like to filter only those with the lowest price, i.e. I expect to get:

```
Shop    Brand    Model    Price
----    -----    -----    -----
Ebay    Sony     S-100    500
Ebay    Dell     D-55     300
Target  Sony     S-200    900
Amazon  Dell     D-33     100
```

and preferably to sort by `Brand` and then by `Model`:

```
Shop    Brand    Model    Price
----    -----    -----    -----
Ebay    Sony     S-100    500
Target  Sony     S-200    900
Amazon  Dell     D-33     100
Ebay    Dell     D-55     300
```

How could I do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would you be happy with database specific sorting?

```
@products.order('brand_id, price')
```

EDIT: Filter and order

EDIT2: Not index, but group by the model

EDIT3: Sort on brand first and then model

EDIT4: Dont stop until there's scope for improvement. A better multifield sort

```
def lowest_priced(products)
  # All products are grouped by the model (key is model, value is array of products belonging to that model)
  per_model = products.group_by{|x|x.model}
  # Hash of lowest products per model
  lowest = {}
  per_model.keys.each do |model|
    # Find lowest priced product for the model
    lowest[model] = per_model[model].min_by{|p| p.price}
  end
  # Sort the values of the hash
  return lowest.values.sort_by{|p| [p.model.brand,p.model]}
end
```

You would ideally refactor the code above so that each function has only one responsibility.

Comment: aah! So you need to group by the model_id, pick the lowest priced and then sort. You could do this in the database with a funky query but it's dicey whether it will be portable or not. I'll update my answer with a ruby solution (mind you this means ALL records will be fetched).

Comment: Selecting all records and using all these enumerable methods will become very slow going with a large amount of data and brings unnecessary complexity. I'd avoid this technique at all costs unless you know you're only ever dealing with small amounts of data.

Comment: You're absolutely right @idlefingers, doing this calculation in ruby would be expensive but I think she's looking to pick up the lowest priced item for each model/brand. This means a query grouped by the model/brand with a "having price = min(price)" clause added leading to a slightly complex query perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this in a single query by joining the tables, grouping to only get one result per model and ordering to come back in the order you want. The following should be along the lines of what you need:

```
Product.joins(:model => :brand).group("models.name").order("products.price, brands.name, models.name")
```

I've guessed your model and brand tables have a column called name or something which is what the model name and brand name is stored in.

Answer (score 0):

Use searchlogic gem. it generates a lot of scopes for searching and ordering. e.g.

```
Product.search(:order => :ascend_by_model)
```

Comment: searchlogic doesnt quite work very well with Rails 3 and has not been maintained or updated for some time.